# Making Apache virtualhosts log to more than one file

Tags: apache, logging

At the moment my virtualhosts look somewhat like this:

```
<VirtualHost 11.111.1.111:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/html/mydomain.com/public
CustomLog /var/log/http/mydomain.com-access-log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This logs all requests for this particular website to its own log file, which I am happy with.

What I would like to do is have all virtualhosts (including this one) also log all of their requests to a shared logfile, in addition to their own logfile.  I'd also like to limit the shared logfile to particular filetypes too (for example just HTML pages or just images).

I'm not sure if this is even possible?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following vhost:

```
<VirtualHost 11.111.1.111:80>
ServerName mydomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/html/mydomain.com/public
#vhost logfile
CustomLog /var/log/http/mydomain.com-access-log combined
#shared logfile of images
setenvIf Request_URI ".(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$" logimg
CustomLog /var/log/http/images-access.log  combined env=logimg
</VirtualHost>
```

Br,
E-raser